# Flutter problem: A problem occurred configuring project ':open_filex'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I am trying to use the [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) in my flutter app. I am getting the following error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':open_filex'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':open_filex:classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-4.1.3.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.jar'.
            > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I understand the problem but I don't know how to resolve this issue. I tried clearing my caches but no success prevailed.

This is my `build.gradle` file under the `android` directory

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.1, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64, locale en-GH)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the android/gradle.properties file and add this:

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

These configuration lines will set default values for trust in SSL certificates.

Save the file and run:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't help.  My "openfile" issue stemmed from Syncfusion's datagrid export feature.